# Using .then in ejs with helper function returns [ object promise ]

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

In my ejs file, I am calling a helper function in another file that returns a mysql result. The problem is the returned value is [ object promise ] even when I am using .then(). I am unsure why.

helper function

```
    var conn = require("../routeFunctions/mySqlConn");


//get the amount of likes
var getLikesCountEjs = function(idOfPost) {
    var query = getLikeCount(idOfPost).q;
    var preparedStatement = getLikeCount(idOfPost).ps;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      conn.query(query, preparedStatement, function (err, result, fields) {
         if (err) {
            reject("problem getting likes count");
          } else {
            resolve(result[0].count);
          }
      });
    });
  }

  //get all likes count
  function getLikeCount(idOfPost) {
    var query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM likes where idOfPost = ?";
    var preparedStatement = [parseInt(idOfPost)];
    return { ps: preparedStatement, q: query };
  }

  //you can return multiple functions 
  module.exports = { getLikesCountEjs : getLikesCountEjs };
```

ejs file where i am calling the function

```
    <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm interactSetLikesTimeLine" id = "setLikes-<%=posts.id%>">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up mr-1 initalLoadSetLikes"> Likes <%= asyncFunctions.getLikesCountEjs(posts.id).then(function(result){ console.log(result); }) %> </i> 
  </a>
```

Comment: You should do this on the nodeJS backend. As can be seen [here](https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/179), it is not possible (nor practical in my opinion)

Comment: EJS files are rendered with the data you pass them. Of course they can't render things that will happen in the future. They can't render what's in the `.then()`, simply because it hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `async` with EJS, [read this issue](https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/179).

Such `async` methods should be done on the nodeJS backend, so you have something like:

```js
app.get('...', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('...', {
    data: await asyncFunctions.getLikesCountEjs(posts.id)
  })
})
```

Should suffice.

Comment: could i add this in my helper function?

Comment: what do you mean? Just execute your helper function like what I roughly have.

Comment: ok. I am very new to node js and async stuff so I am kind of having trouble with it. I am not sure if I am correct but. When I see app.get I am thinking of my route. So I am thinking.. on route request render the page with my helper function loaded in ejs with "await keyword". Then In my ejs, refer to data instead of my actual helper function. This will allow me to use await in ejs without getting an error. Is that correct?

Comment: sorry i misunderstood. I think I get it now

Comment: yep, you appear to understand what I am trying to say! (Using the variable that was passed through render instead of calling the function)